# actionscript can i have symbol with multiple animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, symbols, timeline

im building a multi page flash animation , the background is changeless and symbols come to view with some effect and enter a loop . its possible to add more animation effect on symbols and call them when a button is clicked ?
maybe i can label deferent part of symbol time line and call them with as?
something like this

```
symbol1.loading.play();
```

and

```
symbol1.exit.play();
```

p.s
im new in flash and prefer to do things with code

Answer (score 0):

you can put animation in different moviclip, with first frame blank. As example given you can name movieclips with name as "loading" or "exit"

Comment: tnx , i solved my problem with another way . i used cs6 to convert existing tweens to as3 code and trying to apply them to symbols with as3 . thinking on using greensock seems to be better than flash cc tweens

Comment: using tweenclass make my code very big and hard to underestand , finally i did it with gotoAndPlay . for symbol a1 and lable load a1.gotoAndPlay("load");